# Delete or archive customers?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm working on a user management system, and was curious how you all deal with removing customers ? do you completely delete them from the database or do you archive them (hide them) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my technical opinion, the best approach is to "hide" the customers.  That way you can keep track of historical customers and their behavior.

That said, there are legal reasons why you might have to legally delete them or obfuscate them so their identity unknown.

So, it depends, and it depends on the legal and regulatory framework, as well as the business requirements of what you are working on.